# AngularJS Apache Virtualhost rewrite

Tags: angularjs, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to develop an angular app using a local instance of Apache. I've set up a virtualhost for my application so that when I visit http://abcdefg.com:3000 it points to my local instance. I'm trying to create a rewrite rule within the virtualhost configuration, but I can't seem to get it working.

When I put the following in an .htaccess file it works just fine, but not when I put it in my  configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

Note that my Apache instance is running on port 3000 (I have other things on port 80 at the moment). When using the above in my virtualhost configuration it doesn't seem to load the javascript files properly and I get the following error:

```
GET http://abcdefg.com:3000/public/lib/angular/angular.min.js
GET http://abcdefg.com:3000/public/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js
```

After digging further the server is returning a 400 Bad Request message. Is there anyway I can write my rewrite rules to work inside my virtualhost configuration or am I stuck using an .htaccess file?

Thanks!